# Is Boolean.TRUE rather than true an autoboxing optimization?

Tags: java, autoboxing

I saw the following code and was wondering the intent of the coder. Is it related performance of autoboxing?

```
map.put("doesntMatter", Boolean.TRUE);
```

He could have done:

```
map.put("doesntMatter", true);
```

Any benefits of doing the first?

Comment: I'd say the compiler is smart enough so any of those will have the same effect. - We could do the test, though.

Comment: Either what @acdcjunior said, or at runtime, the JIT will figure this out. So, no real interest ultimately.

Comment: Just checked via Oracles's `javap`, and, good or no good, `map.put("doesntMatter", true)` is converted to `map.put("doesntMatter", Boolean.valueOf(1))`. So it generates one extra instruction (that pushes `1` onto the stack before calling the `valueOf` method) and uses a `invokestatic` instead of a `getstatic` (used in the first statement). I is hard to draw any conclusions from this (because the JIT will come into play when the real time comes; and different compilers generate different bytecodes), but what I just described is what actually happens with Oracle´s `javac` and `javap`.

Comment: Not really a duplicate question,  as this question is asking specifically about the context where a `Boolean`, rather than a `boolean`, is needed.

Answer (score 5):

I've written an example:

```
public class Demo {

    Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();

    void primitive() {
        map.put("a", true);
    }

    void object() {
        map.put("b", Boolean.TRUE);
    }
}
```

look at the bytecode of `primitive()`

```
 0 aload_0
 1 getfield #17 <Demo/map Ljava/util/Map;>
 4 ldc #24 <a>
 6 iconst_1
 7 invokestatic #26 <java/lang/Boolean/valueOf(Z)Ljava/lang/Boolean;>
10 invokeinterface #32 <java/util/Map/put(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;> count 3
15 pop
16 return
```

and the the bytecode of `object()`

```
 0 aload_0
 1 getfield #17 <Demo/map Ljava/util/Map;>
 4 ldc #39 <b>
 6 getstatic #41 <java/lang/Boolean/TRUE Ljava/lang/Boolean;>
 9 invokeinterface #32 <java/util/Map/put(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;> count 3
14 pop
15 return
```

Conclusion:

when using the primitive, there is an extra step calling `Boolean.valueOf()`, but if you run that piece of code often, the JIT compiler will do it's job and optimize it away.

Comment: Im not really sure what we are suppose to see here... Can you please elaborate. Also perhaps also compare it to `Map<String boolean>`?

Comment: @Dgrin91: `Map<String, boolean>` wouldn't compile. I have written a short conclusion.

Comment: @Dgrin91: This is exactly what I was saying `invokestatic #26 <java/lang/Boolean/valueOf(Z)Ljava/lang/Boolean;>`.

Answer (score 1):

The benefits are not in execution time, as this little test code shows :

Results :

```
Time with primitives : 3334779619
Time with Object : 4092034749
Time with primitives : 3670851766
Time with Object : 2748035018
Time with Object : 3738916372
Time with primitives : 2975196722
Time with Object : 2514328271
Time with primitives : 2588980283
Time with Object : 2696162369
Time with primitives : 2615258656
Time with primitives : 2633824223
Time with Object : 2489779261
```

Code :

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Start");

    createWithPrimitive();
    createWithObject();
    createWithPrimitive();
    createWithObject();
    createWithObject();
    createWithPrimitive();
    createWithObject();
    createWithPrimitive();
    createWithObject();
    createWithPrimitive();
    createWithPrimitive();
    createWithObject();

    System.exit(0);
  }

  private static void createWithObject() {
    long time = System.nanoTime();
    Map<Integer, Boolean> testMap = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10000000; i++) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        testMap.put(i, Boolean.TRUE);
      } else {
        testMap.put(i, Boolean.FALSE);
      }
    }

    System.out.println("Time with Object : " + (System.nanoTime() - time));
  }

  private static void createWithPrimitive() {
    long time = System.nanoTime();
    Map<Integer, Boolean> testMap = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10000000; i++) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        testMap.put(i, true);
      } else {
        testMap.put(i, false);
      }
    }

    System.out.println("Time with primitives : " + (System.nanoTime() - time));
  }
}
```

Comment: What if you put `for (int i = 1; i <= 10000000; i++) testMap.put(i, isEven(i));` - I guess the compiler won't be able to optimize that